# Sorting an asp.net drop down list in descending order

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, drop-down-menu

I am sorting my incoming files by my 'Submitted' column (which is a date/time stamp field), however I need it to be in descending order with the most recent file on top.  From my research, it looked like I would simply do this:
view.Sort = "Submitted desc";

Is there something I'm missing?  Here's the entire method:

```
private void PopulatePendingQueryGridView()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn("Spreadsheet", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add(col1);
    DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn("Submitted", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add(col2);
    string folder = Path.Combine(config.BulkQueryUploadFolder, CurrentUser);
    if (Directory.Exists(folder))
    {
        string[] qryFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.xlsx");
        foreach (string qryFile in qryFiles)
        {
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(qryFile);
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Spreadsheet"] = info.Name;
            row["Submitted"] = info.CreationTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
    DataView view = new DataView(dt);
    view.Sort = "Submitted desc";
    pendingQryGridView.DataSource = view;
    pendingQryGridView.DataBind();
    gridUpdatePanel.Update();
}
```

Comment: The sort direction keyword might be case-sensitive. Did you try `Submitted DESC`?

Comment: Try `DESC` (all capital)

Comment: Yes, I tried using DESC in all caps too.  I'd seen examples online using both ways.

Comment: Are you bind to a gridview or dropdownlist? and what is your result?

Answer (score 0):

Change your Submitted column data type to datetime. the sort direction shouldn't be case sensitive, but I'm not sure.

If needed you can set your datagrid field with a specified format.